# how to pass a title via angular-tags to a kendo modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

When I set the kendo modal dialog up like this in my angular app:

```
        <div kendo-window="modalWindow" k-visible="false" 
        k-modal="true" k-title={{myerrors.title}}>
        <label>{{myerrors.messageText}}</label>
    </div>
```

I'm able to open the dialog and pass in the desired message text, but not the title.  What is the proper way to bind the title to a $scope property?

```
 $scope.myerrors = {title: "", msg: ""};
 $scope.showMessage = function (title,msg) {
    $scope.myerrors.messageText = msg;
    $scope.myerrors.title = title;
    $scope.modalWindow.center().open();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div kendo-window="modalWindow" k-visible="false" 
    k-modal="true" k-title="'{{myerrors.title}}'">
    <label>{{myerrors.messageText}}</label>
</div>
```

Notice the title is surrounded by both: **'** and **"** quotes